# update rows having dependencies

Tags: sql, postgresql

We have two tables named `patron` and `cir_transaction`.

In that `patron` table, one column named `patron_id` (primary key) I just update the data of the `patron_id` with other names,
now I have to write a query to

```
update patron set patron_id=" " where patron_id="" like....
**original query**:(update patron set patron_id='" + patronIdTrim + "' where patron_id='" + patronId + "' and library_id=" + SimpleUtility.getLibraryId()));
```

But in executing it shows

> update or delete on table "patron" violates foreign key constraint "fk_111" on table "cir_transaction

I have too try first to update that particular `patron_id` in `cir_transaction` table like :

```
 update cir_transaction set patron_id='" + patronIdTrim + "' where patron_id='" + patronId + "' and library_id=" + SimpleUtility.getLibraryId());
```

it shows error like:

> insert or update on table "cir_transaction" violates foreign key constraint "fk_111"

So tell me now how to update those rows (`patron_id`) in both tables?
Still any one not understand my question please ask me I will tell in detail.

Comment: Use `ON UPDATE CASCADE` foreign keys. For details see Google and the stack overflow search.

Comment: The idea of setting the primary key to a single space seems a little odd.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by another User you have to use "UPDATE CASCADE" to simultaneously update all referenced tables.

Below is an example of how to make the table structure:

```
--main table
CREATE TABLE script_cadastro
(
    cd_sequencia integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    nr_atividade integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    nm_script character varying(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''::character varying,
    nr_versao character varying(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''::character varying,
    observacao character varying(1000) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''::character varying,
    script_conteudo character varying(5000) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''::character   varying, 
    dt_cad date NOT NULL DEFAULT '1900-01-01'::date,
    hr_cad time without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT '00:00:00'::time without time zone,
    CONSTRAINT script_cadastro_pk PRIMARY KEY (cd_sequencia)
);

--table with foreign key
CREATE TABLE script_cadastro_itens
(
   cd_sequencia  INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0                      ,
   versao_script VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''                ,
   usuario       INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0                      ,
   dt_cad        DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '1900-01-01'              ,
   hr_cad        TIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '00:00:00'                ,
   CONSTRAINT script_cadastro_itens_pk PRIMARY KEY (cd_sequencia),
   CONSTRAINT script_cadastro_itens_fk FOREIGN KEY (cd_sequencia) REFERENCES    script_cadastro (cd_sequencia) 
   ON UPDATE CASCADE 
   ON DELETE RESTRICT
 );
```

In my opinion ... should move little in the primary key. Make updates modifying its value as exemplified not you think a good practice, so that the system of the company where I work, we do not simply updates this way.

I hope I helped you!